# C# text file - how to write EOF character

Tags: c#

This has got to be an easy question but I'm not finding anything out there.

I have a text file. I need to put a EOF character at the end so a third party vendor can read the file correctly.

What is the escape character needed to write the end of file character?

I'm not sure if I need to supply any more information, but if I do, let me know.

Thanks

Comment: There is no such character in C#. It is not dependent on C# but it does depend who is going to be reading the file, whether they want a special EOF to identify the file has ended. DOS used ASCII 26, I believe.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use the [StreamWriter class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.aspx), and [Close](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.close.aspx) the file appropriately.  The EOF marker will be handled properly for you.

Comment: use the "using" statement and you don't even have to worry about closing

Comment: Yes, that's fine, as well - provided that you're writing to the file in a single operation, and not needing to encapulate it within another class, etc.

Comment: see thats exactly what I thought. but the dang vendor is telling me its not there

Comment: @Miles: Make sure you're writing the file in the same character encoding that they are trying to use.  It may be an encoding issue that's "messing" them up...

Comment: If, in fact, there is no EOF character make sure you specify the Encoding (like `new StreamWriter(myStream, Encoding.UTF8)` AND use `streamWriter.WriteLine( obj );` (`Write` wasn't working for me).

Comment: StreamWriter doesn't write an explicit EOF character or sequence (such as ASCII char 0x1A). If you open a file written by the StreamWriter in a hex editor you'll see that it just ends.

Answer (score 11):

If you needs to place that EOF char anyways, you could go with:

```
yourStream.WriteByte(0x1A); // dec 26
```

Answer (score 4):

The EOF character is written automatically when using C#'s libraries to write to a text file.

Answer (score 2):

if your stream is FileStream than you can simply:

```
yourStream.SetLength(someUlongLength);
```