# Writing to text file after EOF sign

Tags: c#

Is it possible in C# to write after EOF so that next characters will be ignored by text editor and OS, but still accessible programatically?

E.g.

```
asdf<EOF>ghjklzxcvbm
```

Part after EOF should be ignored (invisible) in text editor.

I've tried with

```
stream.WriteByte(0x1A); // dec 26
```

as written in thread https://stackoverflow.com/a/2194619 and then appending the rest of message, but with no results - text is still visible in editor.

Comment: Surely it depends on the editor whether or not it cares about Control-Z.

Comment: @JohnSaunders how you let text editor to hide characters? forexample, when you open a text file with notepad, how you let notepad to ignore some characters?

Comment: Notepad ignores what it wants to ignore. I'm not sure that it ignores anything. Windows is not Unix.

Comment: @JohnSaunders there is no any want for Notepad!

Comment: @MustafaEkici: I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: @JohnSaunders if my Notepad ignore some characters i go to law for microsoft :)

Comment: @MustafaEkici: I thought you wanted to know how to force Notepad to ignore Ctrl-Z. My point was that this is not possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is probably not easy to do. IF you succeed placing an EOF you probably can't read past it even with your own code. If you use NTFS filesystem maybe you should take a look at alternate data streams http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9387/Manipulate-Alternate-Data-Streams

Alternate datastreams live beside the main stream of the file and is not visible when you open a file.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think your post solves my problem.

Answer (score 0):

it s not possible, if a text editor ignore characters, it will be a big BUG,

 Your referenced thread is different than what you want to do.